# Disable download / install of App for a specific Android Version or Device

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop

I just found out that the android version of my cordova/phonegap based app shows a bug on new android 5 devices (tested on Nexus 4 and Nexus 7).

Not sure if the devices or the os version causes this (my guess: android 5)

The problem is, that a relatively simple page cannot be scrolled - while buttons still responding to touch events.

I'm working on a fix, but until this will be available I'd like to disable the app for all android 5 devices.

So, basically I want to make the app manually incompatible with Android 5.x, until I fixed the problem.

Does anyone know if and how this is possible in Googles PlayStore - preferably without uploading a intermediate version of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  One in the Play Developer console and one by uploading a new APK.  Unfortunately, uploading a new APK is your best solution.

#### Through the Play Developer console

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017

1. login to Developer console https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. select your application
3. click on **APK**
4. click on **Manage excluded devices**
5. type in the name of the device you want to exclude
6. toggle the switch so the red sign shows.
7. click **save** at the bottom

You will need to do this for every device you want to exlcude

#### Through the AndroidManifest.xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

You need to update the AndroidManifest.xml file's `uses-sdk` elem with the `android:maxSdkVersion="integer"` attribute.  In your case:

```
android:maxSdkVersion="19"
```

to exclude lollipop, see https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html .  This will exclude all current & future 5.0 devices so you don't have to keep updating your list.

Comment: thanks for this information. It is a shame that it is not possible to remove a OS level as a targeted system via the dev console. Manually disable devices seems not an option, since I don't know the android version of the each device. Hoping that I soon will find a fix for the scroll problem, I have added a warning in the promo text.

Comment: the google developer console has been changes you should follow these steps for restricting
Sign in to your developer account
Click on app you want to apply restriction
then release management
device catalog
you will see three tabs, all, supported and excluded device list. add your devices to exclude tabs for applying restriction

Comment: How to disable/prevent/stop a specific app version(that has been rollout) from updation on all devices/users?