# How to make app unavailable for a specific version of Android?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'd like to make my app unavailable for Android 7.1 because it doesn't work well with that version.
Is there a way to make it unavailable for Android 7.1 only using the Play Console?

Comment: Should Your app works for the android below than 7.1?

Comment: Set the `minSdkVersion` to `25`, so your app only ships to Android 7.1 and higher devices.

Comment: @SahilGoyal yes it works for below 7.1

Comment: @CommonsWare but i want it to be available for devices with android version below 7.1.... i only want  to exclude 7.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27510943/13485181 Hope it helps you.

Comment: @SahilGoyal this doesn't show me how to exclude android 7.1 unfortunately

Comment: BTW, there was a typo in my earlier comment: you would need `26` so your app ships on 8.0 and higher. But trying to block this in the developer console not only may not be practical today, but it is not going to be reliable over time. You cannot assume that the console will allow you to filter out these devices easily today or tomorrow. I recommend that you refocus your efforts on addressing whatever problems that you believe are uniquely from 7.1 devices.

Comment: Have you considered publishing two APKs/Bundles? One with maxSdkVersion=24 and one with minSdkVersion=26 in the same release. It would still be better to try and find a workaround for devices on SDK 25 however.

Comment: @Pierre I think this is the correct solution. Thank you for sharing, I'll try it in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1 Open Play Console

2 Select Your Application

3 Under Release Select Device Catalogue

4 Than click on Manage Device option and Than Exclude Device

5 Add Filter based on SDK 7.1

6 Than Select all device

and from below right save(Exclude device option)

These steps are according to new google play console Version

Comment: That's a poor option since that will exclude devices who have since received an upgraded version of the OS. You cannot exclude an OS version by excluding a list of devices.